# Hibernate: load a field from a query , but don't insert it to the table

Tags: hibernate

I have a bean with a certain field f1 that should not be mapped into the table , but sometime I do want to load it from some queries (not the table itself)

Can it be done? How?

I've tried declaring it @Transient , but then it doesn't read it from the query , even when I declare `<return-property name="f1" column="f1"/>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mapping it like normal but setting insert and update to false.  Or, you could define it as a formula that just has the column name in the formula.  Hibernate will query it just fine but will know not to try to write it.

Comment: Insertable = false and updateable = false will still cause hibernate to try to read it from the table - and I don't want it. (Also , there's no readable = false)

About the formula - Good idea , but it won't work - because the result is based on other fields in the query , which are not in the table

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question.  You might try adding more details  or a concrete example. Good luck!